# How does Objective-C initialize C struct as property?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Consider below struct:

```
typedef struct _Index {
    NSInteger category;
    NSInteger item;
} Index;
```

If I use this struct as a property:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) Index aIndex;`

When I access it without any initialization right after a view controller `alloc init`, LLDB print it as:

```
(lldb) po vc.aIndex
(category = 0, item = 0)
(lldb) po &_aIndex
0x000000014e2bcf70
```

I am a little confused, the struct already has valid memory address, even before I want to allocate one. Does Objective-C initialize struct automatically? If it is a NSObject, I have to do `alloc init` to get a valid object, but for C struct, I get a valid struct even before I tried to initialize it.

Could somebody explains, and is it ok like this, not manually initializing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of the property are to copy the `struct`, so it doesn't need to be allocated and initialized like an Objective-C object would.  It's given its own space like a primitive type is.

You will need to be careful updating it, as this won't work:

```
obj.aIndex.category = 1;
```

Instead you will need to do this:

```
Index index = obj.aIndex;
index.category = 1;
obj.aIndex = index;
```

This is because the property getter will return a *copy* of the `struct` and not a reference to it (the first snippet is like the second snippet, without the last line that assigns the copy back to the object).

So you might be better off making it a first class object, depending on how it will be used.

Comment: I don't follow, why can't I just use `obj.aIndex.category = 1;`

Comment: Because it will set the new category on a copy of the objects `aIndex` (so that line is like the first 2 lines of my second example).

Comment: I tried it, and it throws compiler error, saying `expression is not assignable`. Seems different with your saying?

Comment: @Wingzero, you can write `obj->_aIndex.category = 1`; But accessing instance variables without properties is bad practice.

Comment: @Wingzero Sounds like the warnings in `clang` have been improved to catch this error.

Comment: @Cy-4AH No you cannot use it, because _aIndex is synthesized in the .m file

Comment: @Wingzero, `@interface Foo : NSObject{ @public Index _aIndex;} @end` and you can directly access object's ivars.

Comment: well it changes a lot for @public.. But still not a good practice :(

Comment: @Cy-4AH Yes, that will work, although exposing instance variables like that is obviously not a good idea.

Comment: @Wingzero, as I wrote before accessing instance variables without properties is bad practice.

Comment: It is also important that the struct is only initialized to zeros, like other "primitive" types.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the subquestion, why you cannot assign to a structure component returned from a getter:
(As a motivation this is, because I have read this Q several times.)

A. This has nothing to do with Cbjective-C. It is a behavior stated in the C standard. You can check it for simple C code:

```
NSMakeSize( 1.0, 2.0 ).width = 3.0; // Error
```

B. No, it is *not* an improvement of the compiler. If it would be so, a warning would be the result, not an error. A compiler developer does not have the liberty to decide what an error is. (There are some cases, in which they have the liberty, but this are explicitly mentioned.)

C. The reason for this error is quite easy:

An assignment to the expression

```
NSMakeSize( 1.0, 2.0 ).width
```

would be legal, if that expression is a l-value. A `.` operator's result is an l-value, if the structure is an l-value:

> A postfix expression followed by the `.` operator and an identifier designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member,82) and is an lvalue if the first expression is an lvalue.

ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, 6.5.2.3

Therefore it would be assignable, if the expression

```
NSMakeSize( 1.0, 2.0 )
```

is an l-value. It is not. The reason is a little bit more complex. To understand that you have to know the links between `.`, `->` and `&`:

In contrast to `.`, `->` always is an l-value.

> A postfix expression followed by the `->` operator and an identifier designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member of the object to which the first expression points, and is an lvalue. 83)

Therefore - that is what footnote 83 explains – `->`, `&`, and `.` has a link:

If you can calculate the address of a structure `S` having a component C with the `&` operator, the expression `(&S)->C` is equivalent to `S.C`. This requires that you can calculate the address of `S`. But you can never do that with a return value, even it is a simple integer …

```
int f(void)
{
  return 1;
}

f()=5; // Error
```

… or a pointer …

```
int *f(void)
{
  return NULL;
}

f()=NULL; // Error
```

You always get the same error: It is not assignable. Because it is a r-value. This is obvious, because it is not clear,

a) whether the way the compiler returns a value, esp. whether he does it in address space.

b) when the time the life time of the returned value is over

Going back to the structure that means that the return value is a r-value. Therefore the result of the `.` operator on that is a r-value. You are not allowed to assign a value to a r-value.

D. The solution

There is a solution to assign to a "returned structure". One might decide, whether it is good or not. Since `->` always is an l-value, you can return a pointer to the structure. Dereferencing this pointer with the `->` operator has always an l-value as result, so you can assign a value to it:

```
// obj.aIndex returns a pointer
obj.aIndex->category = 1;
```

You do not need `@public` for that. (What really is a bad idea.)